# Data preservation after namenode format in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

If I run `hdfs namenode -format` on my active namenode, will I lose all the data in the datanodes which communicate with this namenode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important thing is the META data in your name node. Data nodes might have a copy of the data in the form of replicas. But If the namenode .META is deleted or altered then the data should be lost, as it is a formatting command.